# Manifest with fileprovider compatible with old Android version

Tags: android, fileprovider

To maintain compatibility with **Android 8** for my app I had to add the "provider" tag in the manifest. This is the tag:

```
   <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="xxx.xxx.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

I have implemented everything and **everything is working on android 7/8/9**.

Today a try to install APP on old device (**ANDROID 4**) and this is a error message:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: **Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider**: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "**android.support.v4.content.FileProvider**" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/mywork.activity-4.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/mywork.activity-4, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

**I understood that the problem is due to the fact that on Android4 is not present that library** but I do not want to make two versions of the APP absolutely have two different manifest files.

What solutions can there be? Can you add the library (which andorid4 does not have) manually? Does it conflict with something?

Otherwise I do not understand the sense of **entering the code**

`(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT> = Build.VERSION_CODES.N`)

when I decide whether to use **fileprovider** or the old type of **intent**.

If I have manifest that is **not compatible with versions prior to Build.VERSION_CODES.N**....conditional statement in the code does not make sense.

How could I solve?

Answer (score 0):

most likely `targetApi` should work:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="xxx.xxx.fileprovider"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    android:exported="false"

    tools:targetApi="o">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />

</provider>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, as a value, I must strictly put the same number of APIs that I inserted code side when I go to use it? ... In my specific case I should put as value the 24.
Quite right?

Comment: Same error.
However it is EXCLUSIVELY a problem of DEBUG .... if I create the signed apk and I install MANUALLY the apk on the device WORKS!
I tried change compileSdkVersion = 19 (Android 4.4) and also all the libraries that include but nothing, DexPathList finds errors that do not exist on classes that have always gone ... very strange, for now I am content to at least create the APK signed and then be able to update the old versions ... the problem will be big when I have an exclusive bug on 4.4 ... then I'll have to find a solution.

Comment: @Marios `targetApi` expects letters, not numbers. lowering the `compileSdkVersion`  or `targetSdkVersion` might only break it for later versions. there's an attribute, to remove whole nodes, eg. from a debug `Manifest.xml`, which is `tools:node="remove"`

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#node_markers

Comment: After two days of curses I understood that the problem is elsewhere.
I think it's really a problem with DEX of never buildToolsVersion 27 when using 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
The manifest does not hit anything; removing all the references to the fileprovider (both code side ch eled manifest) the problems of the DEX resurface on other libraries so I think it's all just derived from the fact that I'm using these buildtools.
I know that by lowering compileSdkVersion I break compatibility.I did it only to try and debug a device with ANDROID 4.4 ... a momentary thing.Thanks!